# How to fix the sending query to MySQL? Error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have setting the code and query with database. I think everything is correct with PDO Connection to MySQL but the record did not go to the database.

// Includes start
// Connection

```
<?php   
    $DSN = 'mysql:host = localhost; dbname = cms4.2.1';
    $ConnectingDB = new PDO($DSN, 'root', '');
?>
```

// Redirect function

```
<?php
    function Redirect_to($New_Location) {
            header("Location:".$New_Location);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

// Errors handling

```
<?php
    session_start();

    function ErrorMessage(){
        if (isset($_SESSION["ErrorMessage"])){
            $Output = "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">";
            $Output .= htmlentities($_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]);
            $Output .= "</div>";
            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = null;
            return $Output;
        }
    }

    function SuccessMessage() {
        if (isset($_SESSION["SuccessMessage"])) {
            $Output = "<div class=\"alert alert-success\">";
            $Output .= htmlentities($_SESSION["SuccessMessage"]);
            $Output .= "</div>";
            $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"] = null;
            return $Output;
        }
    }
?>
```

// Includes End

// The code

```
<?php require_once("Includes/DB.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("Includes/Functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("Includes/Sessions.php"); ?>

<?php
   if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
      $Category = $_POST["CategoryTitle"];
      $Admin = "Abdullah";
     date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Riyadh");
     $CurrentTime = time();
     $DateTime = strftime("%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S", $CurrentTime);
     if (empty($Category)) {
        $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "All fields must be filled out";
        Redirect_to("Categories.php");
     } else if (strlen($Category) < 3) {
        $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Category is short";
        Redirect_to("Categories.php");
     } else if (strlen($Category) > 49) {
        $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Category is too long";
        Redirect_to("Categories.php");
     } else {
       // Insert to database
       // The problem starts here I think
       global $ConnectingDB;
       $sql = "INSERT INTO category(title,author,datetime)";
       $sql .= "VALUES(:categoryName,:adminName,:dateTime)";
       $stmt = $ConnectingDB->prepare($sql);
       $stmt -> bindValue(':categoryName',$Category);
       $stmt -> bindValue(':adminName',$Admin);
       $stmt -> bindValue(':dateTime',$DateTime);
       $Execute = $stmt -> execute();

       if ($Execute) {
       $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"] = "Category Added Successfully";
          Redirect_to("Categories.php");
       } else {
          $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Something went wrong";
          Redirect_to("Categories.php");
       }
   }
}
?>
```

The execute message always keeps "Something went wrong"

When I go to normal MySQL query system everything is ok. But I want to complete my work on PDO.

Comment: Then print out PDO's errorInfo

Comment: What data type is `datetime` in your table ?

Comment: @kuh-chan I tried errorInfo and I got this array: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: @Cid It's VARCHAR 50

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [pdoexception](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.pdoexception.php)

then you will be able to print your errors and exceptions.

```
try{
   $stmt = $ConnectingDB->prepare($sql);
   $stmt -> bindValue(':categoryName',$Category);
   $stmt -> bindValue(':adminName',$Admin);
   $stmt -> bindValue(':dateTime',$DateTime);
   $Execute = $stmt -> execute();
}catch( PDOException $e ) {
  print $e->getMessage();
}
```

[pdo should i try/catch every query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023169/pdo-should-i-try-catch-every-query)

Hope that help you.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer. Try to earn the few reputation points you need to comment if you need some clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting space before VALUES or after the closing bracket of the first row just like I did below, sometimes the query doesn't work because of bad written syntax.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO category(title,author,datetime) ";
```

OR

```
$sql .= " VALUES(:categoryName,:adminName,:dateTime)";
```

This might not be the problem but it's good practice.

Comment: That's not a problem since he's using parenthesis to define the fields. [test it yourself](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6FUrEq7f5u9cbBLp4T3oMs/0)